# Routing audio to bluetooth isnt working from BroadcastReceiver on ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to change audio route to bluetooth by 2 ways:

1. From ui thread - works ok.
2. From BroadcastReceiver that listening to bluetooth connection changes - ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED and ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED - isnt work

when bluetooth device is connected i am trying to set audio route to bluetooth, but the audio route isnt move to bluetooth.

I am using this code to set audio route to bluetooth for both ways :

```
AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
AudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
AudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

I ma using these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

my BroadcastReceiver -

```
mBluetoothConnectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                AudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                AudioManager.startBluetoothSco();

            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                AudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                AudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    registerReceiver(mBluetoothConnectionReceiver, filter);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks